# How to use Pandas mask method on the part of Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

With the data frame constructed as below, but with many more objects (structured as `object1` columns) I want to remove (replace with `np.nan`) all values of `var1`, `var2`, `var3` when there are smaller than 0 or greater than 100.

```
example_df = {('meta_info', 'time'): {0: 2100, 1: 2200, 2: 2300, 3: 2400, 4: 100},
 ('meta_info', 'counter'): {0: 0.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 3.0, 4: 4.0},
 ('meta_info', 'measurement_id'): {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1},
 ('object1', 'grp'): {0: '0', 1: '0', 2: '0', 3: '0', 4: '0'},
 ('object1', 'id'): {0: '376690',
  1: '376690',
  2: '376690',
  3: '376690',
  4: '376690'},
 ('object1', 'var1'): {0: 34.405149821218195,
  1: 25.047388024508773,
  2: 94.12283547956514,
  3: -38.34383022173205,
  4: 60.15259222044418},
 ('object1', 'var2'): {0: 40.470001220703125,
  1: 40.369998931884766,
  2: 40.277000427246094,
  3: 40.18899917602539,
  4: 40.10200119018555},
 ('object', 'var1'): {0: -4.453429468309658,
  1: 82.84217089703611,
  2: 145.2084949734712,
  3: 79.83440766416545,
  4: 87.39526160763526},
 ('object', 'var2'): {0: 34.0,
  1: 33.70000076293945,
  2: 33.900001525878906,
  3: 34.0,
  4: 34.0},
 ('object', 'var3'): {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0}}

example_df = pd.DataFrame(example_df)
```

I was trying to use `pd.DataFrame.mask` here, but following code fails:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
z = example_df.loc[:, idx[:, ['var1', 'var2', 'var3']]]
example_df.mask((z < 0) | (z > 100))
```

as it removes all values of other columns than those within `z`.

This is confusing as documentation says:

> cond : boolean Series/DataFrame, array-like, or callable
>       Where `cond` is False, keep the original value. Where
>       True, replace with corresponding value from `other`.

so I assume that first 5 columns, which are not part of `z` view are not checked - otherwise only `(object1, id)` would be replaced with `NaN` as it is the only columns with values outside the range. Why those columns are filled with `NaN` then? Is there any other method that would allow me to check selected part of the `DataFrame` at once?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need replace filtered DataFrame `z`, because boolean mask is from filtered `DataFrame`:

```
print (z.mask((z < 0) | (z > 100)))
     object1                object                
        var1       var2       var1       var2 var3
0  34.405150  40.470001        NaN  34.000000  0.0
1  25.047388  40.369999  82.842171  33.700001  0.0
2  94.122835  40.277000        NaN  33.900002  0.0
3        NaN  40.188999  79.834408  34.000000  0.0
4  60.152592  40.102001  87.395262  34.000000  0.0
```

And if want assign output back assign to filtered DataFrame:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
z = example_df.loc[:, idx[:, ['var1', 'var2', 'var3']]]

example_df.loc[:, idx[:, ['var1', 'var2', 'var3']]] = z.mask((z < 0) | (z > 100))
print (example_df)
  meta_info                        object1                                \
       time counter measurement_id     grp      id       var1       var2   
0      2100     0.0              1       0  376690  34.405150  40.470001   
1      2200     1.0              1       0  376690  25.047388  40.369999   
2      2300     2.0              1       0  376690  94.122835  40.277000   
3      2400     3.0              1       0  376690        NaN  40.188999   
4       100     4.0              1       0  376690  60.152592  40.102001   

      object                  
        var1       var2 var3  
0        NaN  34.000000  0.0  
1  82.842171  33.700001  0.0  
2        NaN  33.900002  0.0  
3  79.834408  34.000000  0.0  
4  87.395262  34.000000  0.0
```